# JUnit 5: Difference between BeforeEachCallback and BeforeTestExecutionCallback

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit5-extension-model

I can't find any ressources explaining what exactly the difference between `BeforeEachCallback` and `BeforeTestExecutionCallback` in the JUnit Jupiter extension model is. (I am of course also interested in the "After"-variants)

To my understanding, the following timeline describes what is happening:

`BeforeEach` - `BeforeTestExecution` - `Actual execution of the test` - `AfterTestExecution` - `AfterEach`

I suppose that `BeforeTestExecution` exists so you can execute code after all the `BeforeEach` callbacks have been worked on but before the actual test execution. However this is still unclear to me, because everyone could just use `BeforeTestExecution` instead of `BeforeEach` and the order of execution of these callbacks is random again.

So what is `BeforeTestExecution` exactly for and what happens if you use this callback in multiple extensions at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Javadocs ([here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeTestExecutionCallback.html) and [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeEachCallback.html)) don't make a clear distinction between them but the [JUnit5 docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks-before-after-execution) include the following:

> `BeforeTestExecutionCallback` and `AfterTestExecutionCallback` define the APIs for Extensions that wish to add behavior that will be executed immediately before and immediately after a test method is executed, respectively. As such, these callbacks are well suited for timing, tracing, and similar use cases. If you need to implement callbacks that are invoked around `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` methods, implement `BeforeEachCallback` and `AfterEachCallback` instead.

So, if you want to wrap **just** the test execution without any of the setup then use `BeforeTestExecutionCallback`. The docs go on to suggest timing and logging test execution as possible use cases for `BeforeTestExecutionCallback`.

Comment: Also helpful: the picture in https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-execution-order.